# docker-compose can't find file while creating docker image

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have project structure like this

```
proj
|
|----------tests
|           |-----integration
|                       |------------docker-compose.yml
|---------Dockerfile 
|
|---------requirements.txt
|
|---------setup.py
```

`Dockerfile` is

```
...
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
...
```

`docker-compose.yml` file is

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  proj-test:
    build:
      context: ..
      network: host
      dockerfile: ../Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
    environment:
      PG_UNITTEST_DB: "postgresql://testuser:testpassword@postgres_db/testdb"
  postgres_db:
    image:  postgis/postgis
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testpassword
      POSTGRES_USER: testuser
      POSTGRES_DB: testdb
```

I build docker compose using this command

```
$proj  docker-compose -f tests/integration/docker-compose.yml build
```

This gives error

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

as it is looking for `'requirements.txt'` in the `tests` folder. How should I tell it to look at the root? Is it something that can be achieved using docker volume? I don't have much experience working docker volumes.

Comment: As the current folder is "integration", maybe you could try `../requirements.txt`

Comment: Do you mean changing in Dockerfile? This will fail while creating docker image from root proj folder.

Comment: Does your Dockerfile `COPY` the file into the image correctly?  I'd also expect `context: ..` to be interpreted relative to the location of the `docker-compose.yml` file; you probably need `context: ../..` (and then `dockerfile: Dockerfile` will be the default and `network: host` should be unnecessary; you can use the shorthand `build: ../..`).

Comment: What should be the ```COPY``` command here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Dockerfile you should copy the `requirements.txt` file first and then run the installation of the requirements.

```
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../requirements.txt ()

Comment: Oh, that's right. I'll edit it. Try it now.

Comment: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder642935549/requirements.txt: no such file or directory

Comment: worked after adding this command                                                                                  
```context: ../..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile```

Comment: Yes, indeed I was emulating your file structure and got that was the solution. You can always run `RUN ls 'l` in your Dockerfile to see what's been copied.